# How to understand source index in muilti-index NEST query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have two indices in my ElasticSearch, let's name them "trusted" and "untrusted". Both indices have the same template/fields/settings.

Based on some flag I perform a NEST query to one or both indices.

```
var indices = request.IncludeUntrustedSources
            ? new[] {"trusted", "untrusted"}
            : new[] {"trusted"};

var searchResponse = await _client.SearchAsync<SearchResultItem>(c => c
    .Query(q => q.Bool(_ => query))
    .Index(indices)
    .Sort(ss => ss
         .Descending(SortSpecialField.Score))
    .From(skip)
    .Size(perPage)
```

The SearchResultItem type is a simple POCO. I want to set the value of the field "TrustedSource" of SearchResultItem to *true* or *false* depending on the source index.

How can I understand from which index each item came?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting matched documents from `searchResponse.Documents` you can get results from `searchResponse.Hits` which also contains search results metadata like `Index` which will help you distinguish matched document source.

```
searchResponse.Hits
    .Select(x =>
        x.Index == "trusted" 
            ? x.Source with { TrustedSource = true } 
            : x.Source with { TrustedSource = false });
    
record SearchResultItem(int Id, bool TrustedSource);
```